# Improve signalr website performance by deviding the load to diffrent servers

Tags: asp.net, signalr

It is possible to divide the load of signalr website like i want to divide the user login and all operation to other server and data operation to other server so performance improve. the performance is very important for me to make 1500 user online and connected. and also want to catch user data.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. You can actually do 2 things:

- Use the SignalR scale out feature to have redundant SignalR server which guarantee broadcasts reach all connected users, regardless of the specific instance they are connected to.
- Split you application in multiple services, where for example only one does push messaging with SignalR and the other ones **app logic**, and then you make the **app logic** ones clients of the **messaging** application, so they can notify about messages to be eventually pushed to connected clients (you could even use some middleware for messaging, like event bus or similar, to increase decoupling). You can have dedicated hubs for the services, and different ones for clients

It's hard to give more detail, but you definitely have several options available.

Comment: I don't have any particular suggestion, also because that could depend on how you want to approach the problem. I'm not aware of "big" frameworks relying on SignalR for complex architectures, but it could be my ignorance.  I know about smaller frameworks to go from plain SignalR to more generic event-based patterns, but overall, you do not need anything special IMO and it's probably a good idea to start simple and then see if you need more to remove complexity.